# which is the best frame work for game development in android

Tags: android, iphone, game-engine

i am a beginner on game development. Can anybody suggest a best game frame work for mobile game development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your skills and your aims and goals. If you want to create a simple (or advanced AAA quality) Android game you can use Unreal Engine(free), Unity(p2p) or App Game Kit (p2p).

Answer (score 0):

Best one and most popular is Unity
it has a 3d and a relatively new 2d modes u can use
and for my and many others opinion it's the best Game engine out there

read more:
https://unity3d.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think for beginners as well as pro developer unity is a best platform to create games and the most important thing is that it is cross platform and provides a really good documentation give it a try.